# Loop through table and delete some rows in procedural mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I got a huge table (1b records) like this:
  char(3), char(3), date, [6 more ints].

I am looking for a very simple functionality in procedural mysql but can't find it: delete the row at the current cursor position.

What I need to do is:

1. sort the table by the (char, char, date) index
2. set the current row to the first row
3. set rank to 0
4. if rank > max_rank, delete the current row.
5. go to next row; add 1 to rank
6. possibly reset rank to 0 if any of the 3 values in the index have changed
7. go to 4

In pseudo-C# it's so simple:

```
var b = new List<Row>(1000000000) { ... };
b.Sort():
var r = 0;
var prev_b = b[0];
for (var i = 0; i < b.Count; i++)
{
  if (r > mr) { b.RemoveAt(i); i--; }
  if (b[i].x != prev_b.x) r = 0; 
  else r++;
  prev_b = b;
}
```

IF it is impossible to do it so efficiently in mysql, what is the next best way?

My ideas (all as a mysql procedure):

Idea I:

1. loop through the table and create an array of keys of the rows that need to be deleted
2. split the array into e.g. 1000000 smaller arrays
3. for each small array, create and execute a DELETE statement which deletes rows with those keys

Idea II:

1. loop through the table and insert rows that should NOT be deleted into another new table, one by one.
2. drop the old table and rename the new

Idea III:

1. loop through the table and insert rows that should NOT be deleted into another new table. insert in batches of e.g. 10000 rows.
2. drop the old table and rename the new

Which idea is the best?

Right now I use PHP for this! If I can count correctly, 3 COPIES OF MY DATA are used in this process: ONE is my data that is always stored on hard disc (and I would like to directly deal with it), THE SECOND is the buffer of the result of `mysql_query()` PHP function calls [perhaps also in memory or on hard disc], and THE THIRD is the actual PHP array which finally enables me to loop through and delete.

Comment: What is the inner-logic of the function that returns a boolean? It's hard to help without knowing this. Also, show a result set sample and what it should look like at the end. Why `DELETE FROM Table WHERE [some condition]` doesn't work for you?

Comment: You could possibly do any complicated check for which records to delete in a MySQL stored procedure. However assuming that isn't possible I would be inclined to create a temp table, insert the ids to be deleted into that (can be done easily in bulk, hundreds of values at a time), then do the delete by joining that table against your main table and deleting the matching rows.

Comment: @plalx: The function considers "the rank" of a row. I have clarified it above.

Comment: I'm sorry, are you actually comparing C# with Mysql? Aren't they two completely different things?

Comment: @geomagas: They are indeed completely different things.

Comment: So what's the point? Or better yet, what's the motivation? I'm curious.

Comment: @geomagas: To explain what kind of efficiency I am dreaming to approach with mySQL. After all, I do not want any c#-specific task implemented in mySQL. In fact, I want the opposite: to implement an SQL-specific task in an SQL.

Comment: Ok, since that's what you want, and since `DELETE FROM Table WHERE [some condition]` is SQL-specific enough, I'll repeat @plalx's question: _Why wouldn't this work for you_? As an aside: Why do we have to make things even more complicated by bringing php into this?

Comment: For two reasons: 1) Because "[some condition]" is not easy (possible?) to express in sql, as explained in details in my question. 2) Because the table is 1 billion records but is in use 24/7 and cannot stay locked for a long time. To the aside, php was my workaround as I was unable to solve it in mysql.